# Mesh partitioner with user-defined overlap

Tags: finite-element, computational-geometry, mesh-generation, mesh, partitioning

I am looking for a mesh partitioner, where I can specify overlap, for example h = 3. 
I have looked into metis, but I wasn't able to find such a functionality.

Is there any other package which provides this functionality?

Comment: You could always use a package such as `METIS` to construct a set of non-overlapping partitions, and then expand them yourself to achieve the desired overlap, via a breadth-first strategy for instance.

Comment: thanks, I ll try to look into it in this way, although I would prefer to find suitable package, which does that.